# print unique lines based on field

Tags: awk

Would like to print unique lines based on first field , keep the first occurrence of that line and remove duplicate other occurrences.

Input.csv

```
10,15-10-2014,abc
20,12-10-2014,bcd
10,09-10-2014,def
40,06-10-2014,ghi
10,15-10-2014,abc
```

Desired Output:

```
10,15-10-2014,abc
20,12-10-2014,bcd
40,06-10-2014,ghi
```

Have tried below command and in-complete

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }  { !seen[$1]++ } END { for ( i in seen) print $0}' Input.csv
```

Looking for your suggestions ...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You put your test for "seen" in the action part of the script instead of the condition part. Change it to:

```
awk -F, '!seen[$1]++' Input.csv
```

Yes, that's the whole script:

```
$ cat Input.csv
10,15-10-2014,abc
20,12-10-2014,bcd
10,09-10-2014,def
40,06-10-2014,ghi
10,15-10-2014,abc
$
$ awk -F, '!seen[$1]++' Input.csv
10,15-10-2014,abc
20,12-10-2014,bcd
40,06-10-2014,ghi
```

Comment: @AVN - you should checkmark this answer so it'll be "answered".

Comment: @MichaelChaney Its always good policy to mark a question as answered, but it I always suggest that you should wait some hour, it may be some having a better answer.  But I doubt it here  :)

Comment: @Jotne Agreed, but in this case it's very unlikely that a better answer will come along.  I've had many answers where the original asker modded the answer up, commented with a "thank you" but apparently didn't know what the checkmark is for.  Just making sure Ed gets his points here as they're well-deserved.

Comment: I'm slowly making my way through 'The AWK Programming Language' but could someone add an explanation here? Why no braces? Where is the print statement? Thanks, and apologies if this is rather basic. I'm not very far in the book yet

Comment: @Ben If there are no curly braces the default action is to print the whole line if the pattern matches.  The pattern `!seen[$1]++` will be true if `$1` hasn't been added to the associative array, and false otherwise.  So it will print each line the first time `$1` is seen.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
awk -F, '{ if (!($1 in a)) a[$1] = $0; } END '{ for (i in a) print a[i]}' input.csv
```

Comment: It will produce the unique output as requested but it will scramble the order of the output lines due to the `in` operator and it's a lot more coding than the idiomatic awk approach (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

typo there in syntax.

> awk '{ if (!($1 in a)) a[$1] = $0; } END { for (i in a) print a[i]}'