# Linux read log file and filter to get the same type of log messages only once

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, grep, uniq

In my log file I have three type of log messages: info, warning, and error. I want to grab only the error messages, but as there are different type of error messages and the same error message may appear more than once in the log file, I only want to grab each type of error
only once. What command can I use in Ubuntu terminal? I have tried:

```
grep -E 'level=error' server.log | sort --unique
```

But this gives me 'info' and 'warning' messages too.

I then used this command but still I get all three types of messages, not just the error messages.

```
grep 'error' server.log | uniq -f 1
```

the argument -f 1 is to skip the timestamp field since it will always be unique.

For example, my log messages are:

```
.
.
.
11-03-2020 11:53:32" level=info msg="Starting up" file="etc/load/startwith.txt"
11-03-2020 11:53:33" level=info msg="Started" file="etc/load/startwith.txt"
11-03-2020 11:54:29" level=warning msg="Some fields missing" file="etc/load/startwith.php" 
11-03-2020 11:54:47" level=info msg="Started the process" file="etc/load/startwith.php" 
11-03-2020 11:54:51" level=info msg="Connecting to database" file="etc/db/dbinfo.php" 
11-03-2020 11:54:53" level=error msg="Database connection failed" file="etc/db/dbinfo.php"  
11-03-2020 13:26:22" level=info msg="Started back-up process" file="etc/load/startwith.php" 
11-03-2020 13:26:23" level=info msg="Starting up" file="etc/load/startwith.txt"
11-03-2020 13:26:26" level=error msg="Start up failed" file="etc/db/startwith.php" 
11-03-2020 13:26:27" level=info msg="Starting up" file="etc/load/startwith.txt"
11-03-2020 13:26:31" level=error msg="Start up failed" file="etc/db/startwith.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:32" level=info msg="Starting up" file="etc/load/startwith.txt"
11-03-2020 13:26:35" level=warning msg="Duplicate fields found" file="etc/load/startwith.php" 
11-03-2020 13:26:36" level=info msg="Started the process" file="etc/load/startwith.php" 
11-03-2020 13:26:37" level=info msg="Connecting to database" file="etc/db/dbinfo.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:38" level=info msg="Success. Connected to the database" file="etc/db/db-success.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:38" level=info msg="Inserting data to database" file="etc/db/dboperation.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:39" level=warning msg="Null fields found" file="etc/db/dboperation.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:39" level=info msg="Data inserted" file="etc/db/dboperation.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:39" level=info msg="Disconnected" file="etc/db/dboperation.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:43" level=info msg="Inserting data to database" file="etc/db/dboperation.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:43" level=error msg="Required data missing" file="etc/db/dboperation.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:44" level=info msg="Inserting data to database" file="etc/db/dboperation.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:44" level=error msg="Required data missing" file="etc/db/dboperation.php"
.
.
.
```

The expected output for Errors from the above logs (3 different types of errors, not total error occurrences) would be:

```
11-03-2020 11:54:53" level=error msg="Database connection failed" file="etc/db/dbinfo.php" 
11-03-2020 13:26:31" level=error msg="Start up failed" file="etc/db/startwith.php"
11-03-2020 13:26:44" level=error msg="Required data missing" file="etc/db/dboperation.php"
```

So essentially I need to filter the log file to get the error messages and having only one error for each type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [awk to print unique lines based on column field:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867277/awk-to-print-unique-lines-based-on-column-field)

Comment: Sorry, it does not answer my questions since he is comparing (hence excluding) the exact duplicates of lines including the timestamp whereas I want to only compare after the timestamp.

Comment: So... `awk '!seen[$4]++'`... He uses `,` as field separator and uses first field. So use another field separator and another field....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```
awk '/error/ && !seen[$4]++'
```

Or use quotes as separator to include the full `msg="this text"` message like:

```
awk -F'"' '/error/ && !seen[$3]++'
```

You could do it without awk - `grep error` then `nl` number lines then `sort -u` sort unique on the field with `msg=`, then re-sort on line numbers and remove line numbers with `cut`. Alternatively the `msg="part"` could be extracted with `sed` to ease up `sort` tokenization. Like this:

```
grep error | sed 's/.* msg="\([^"]*\)"/\1\t&/' | nl -w1 |
sort -t $'\t' -u -k2,2 | sort -n -k1 | cut -f3-
```

Comment: could you describe what `!seen[$4]++` does?

Comment: [It's described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work/159734)

Comment: Thanks Kamil, if I wanted to filter all three type of messages (info, warning, error) in a large log file how would I modify this `'/error/ && !seen[$4]++'` command?

Comment: `awk '/error/'` is like `grep error`. Just remove the `'/error/ &&` part

Answer (score 0):

The command `uniq -f 1` splits by spaces. It has no effect, because the string after the first space, the time, is unique.

Use `uniq -s 20` instead. This ignores the first 20 characters.

It works for time stamps, because they have a fixed length in most cases.