# Grep only last line with latest datetimes in a text file

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk, grep

I have a logfile in a Linux OS (redhat) which inserts events of a database. The file looks like this:

```
2021-08-04 09:35:00.212 +03 [100] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:35:20.276 +03 [101] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:36:05.223 +03 [104] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:36:20.823 +03 [305] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:37:00.299 +03 [322] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:37:50.350 +03 [328] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:38:20.822 +03 [340] FATAL: password fail for z
2021-08-04 09:38:22.500 +03 [370] FATAL: password fail for z
2021-08-04 09:38:50.210 +03 [420] FATAL: password fail for z
2021-08-04 09:39:01.372 +03 [423] FATAL: password fail for z
```

I want to get only lines with the latest datetime for each user(x,y,z). So it should look like below:

```
  2021-08-04 09:36:05.223 +03 [104] FATAL: password fail for x
  2021-08-04 09:37:50.350 +03 [328] FATAL: password fail for y
  2021-08-04 09:39:01.372 +03 [423] FATAL: password fail for z
```

Comment: Please add your attempt

Comment: You can't do that with `grep`. You could try to build something out of `sort` and `uniq`, but really this is more of a job for a scripting language - `python` or `perl` or `awk` or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to get lines that have unique value on the latest column.
<sup>[print unique lines based on field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867277/print-unique-lines-based-on-field)</sup>

---

To ensure those are the latest (datatime), I'd assume the following

- The file is always sorted from old to new

Therefore, if we;

- Reverse the file (to go from `new -> old`)
- Get the unique user rows
- Reverse it again (to go from `old -> new`)

Will get the last failed attempts for each user:

```sh
tac log.txt | awk -F" " '!_[$9]++' | tac
```

---

Example on my local machine:

```
$
$ cat log.txt
2021-08-04 09:35:00.212 +03 [100] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:35:20.276 +03 [101] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:36:05.223 +03 [104] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:36:20.823 +03 [305] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:37:00.299 +03 [322] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:37:50.350 +03 [328] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:38:20.822 +03 [340] FATAL: password fail for z
2021-08-04 09:38:22.500 +03 [370] FATAL: password fail for z
2021-08-04 09:38:50.210 +03 [420] FATAL: password fail for z
2021-08-04 09:39:01.372 +03 [423] FATAL: password fail for z
$
$ tac log.txt | awk -F" " '!_[$9]++' | tac
2021-08-04 09:36:05.223 +03 [104] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:37:50.350 +03 [328] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:39:01.372 +03 [423] FATAL: password fail for z
$
```

Comment: I had a similar solution so upvoted instead. You could also achieve this with `sort -k2r $file  | awk '!array[$NF]++' | sort -k9`

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

data_str = '''2021-08-04 09:35:00.212 +03 [100] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:35:20.276 +03 [101] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:36:05.223 +03 [104] FATAL: password fail for x
2021-08-04 09:36:20.823 +03 [305] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:37:00.299 +03 [322] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:37:50.350 +03 [328] FATAL: password fail for y
2021-08-04 09:38:20.822 +03 [340] FATAL: password fail for z
2021-08-04 09:38:22.500 +03 [370] FATAL: password fail for z
2021-08-04 09:38:50.210 +03 [420] FATAL: password fail for z
2021-08-04 09:39:01.372 +03 [423] FATAL: password fail for z'''
holder = defaultdict(list)
for entry in data_str.split('\n'):
    fields = entry.split(' ')
    holder[fields[-1]].append(datetime.strptime(fields[0] + ' ' + fields[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
for user, date_time_lst in holder.items():
    print(f'{user} --> {max(date_time_lst)}')
```

output

```
x --> 2021-08-04 09:36:05.223000
y --> 2021-08-04 09:37:50.350000
z --> 2021-08-04 09:39:01.372000
```